# How do you use nested for loops to print out the following pattern in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

How can you use nested for loops to print out the following pattern in python? So you don't have to write 7 print functions to print the pattern.

```
1

0 1

1 0 1

0 1 0 1

1 0 1 0 1

0 1 0 1 0 1

1 0 1 0 1 0 1
```

Comment: there are multiple ways, which ones have you tried so far?

Comment: I have tried to do for i in range(7): since there are 7 rows, but I do not know how to get the alternating numbers.

Comment: @Chris Hui - as you see, you don't need to write 7 print functions ... and you only need *ONE* loop (vs. "nested loops").  Please be sure to upvote the replies you've found helpful, and please "accept" the reply that works best for you :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
s = ''
for i in range(1, 8):
    s = str(i % 2) + s
    print(s)
```

Answer (score 2):

You are on the right track with your comment, here is one option using `insert()`:

```
start = [1]
no_rows = 7

for i in range(no_rows):
    print(start)
    start.insert(0, 1 if start[0]==0 else 0)
```

Which gives:

```
[1]
[0, 1]
[1, 0, 1]
[0, 1, 0, 1]
[1, 0, 1, 0, 1]
[0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1]
[1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1]
```

If you want each line to be formatted as a `str` opposed to a `list`, then you can change `print(start)` to `print(' '.join([str(s) for s in start]))`, which gives:

```
1
0 1
1 0 1
0 1 0 1
1 0 1 0 1
0 1 0 1 0 1
1 0 1 0 1 0 1
```

As per Patrick Haugh's comment, you could instead simply replace `print(start)` with `print(*start)` to print the list of integers as a `str`.

Comment: I'd recommend `print(*start)` over `join`.

Comment: Was not aware of this, I will add to my answer. Thanks, I learned something!

Comment: Can you do one  where inner loop parameter depends on outer loop? I am supposed to learn how to do it with an inner loop and I haven't learned what does the insert syntax do.

Comment: The `insert()` method docs are here: https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/list/insert. It takes two arguments, the index where you would like to insert an element, and that element you would like to insert.

Answer (score 2):

Not containing loop but an example of recursive function so that you push further:

```
>>> def foo(length_max, list_=[1]):
...     print(list_)
...     if len(list_)==length_max:
...         return
...     return foo(length_max, [int(not bool(list_[0]))] + list_)
...
>>> foo(7)
[1]
[0, 1]
[1, 0, 1]
[0, 1, 0, 1]
[1, 0, 1, 0, 1]
[0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1]
[1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1]
```

Comment: You need to add your addition to the other end of the list.  The first digit is meant to alternate

Answer (score 1):

As I can see, this is the contest of how many people do *not* answer the question, which was about using nested loops... Ok, here we go, this is my approach: :-)

```
import numpy as np

n = 7
for i in range(n):
    print(1-np.mod(np.arange(i+1), 2)[::-1])
```

Answer (score 1):

This is not an answer in pure python, it makes use of `numpy` and `scipy`, but I think this is a great question because of the matrix you're trying to describe.

You may not be intending this, but your output matches the lower triangle of a  [Toeplitz matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Toeplitz_matrix).

Because of the way you alternate, every diagonal will have the same value.  Therefore, you could use `scipy` to produce your output.

***Setup***

```
num = 7
out = [1,0]*((num // 2)+1)
out = out[:num]

from scipy.linalg import toeplitz
```

---

```
res = toeplitz(out)
res[np.triu_indices_from(res, k=1)] = -1
for row in res:
    print(' '.join(map(str, row[row!=-1])))
```

```
1
0 1
1 0 1
0 1 0 1
1 0 1 0 1
0 1 0 1 0 1
1 0 1 0 1 0 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try this:

```
def run():
    data = [1]
    iterations = 7
    for i in range(iterations):
        print_data(data)
        data.append(i % 2)
    print_data(data)

def print_data(dat):
    print(' '.join(d for d in dat[::-1]))
```

This solution has the added benefit of not using `insert`, which is `O(n)` and replacing an if-statement with a mathematical expression.

Answer (score 0):

This is the long but simple solution

```
count = -1 # Count where in the loop we are
switch = 1 # Switch between 0 and 1
start = 1  # Switch which varibale we start the line with
for i in range(8):
    print()
    count += 1
    start = switch
    for j in range(8):
        if j != count:
            if switch == 0:
                print("1 ", end='') #end= means dont print a new line character
                switch = 1
            else:
                print("0 ", end='')
                switch = 0
        if j == count:
            if start == 1:
                switch = 0
            else:
                switch = 1
            break #Break loop as we have printed as many characters as we want
print() # Print to end the line
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this :

```
    import os
    import re
    import sys

    def print_pattern(num):
        if(num == 1):
            print("1",end="\n")
            return
        elif(num%2 == 1):
            print("1",end=" ")
            print_pattern(num-1)
        else:
            print("0",end=" ")
            print_pattern(num-1)

    number = int(input("Enter the steps"))
    for i in range(1,number+1):
        print_pattern(i)
```

Answer (score 0):

One more solution not using nested loops, instead using a single loop and binary representations.

```
solution = 1
for i in range(7):
    out_str = f'{solution:b}'
    print(' '.join(out_str[::-1]))
    solution = solution << 1
    if i > 0 and i % 2 == 1:
        solution |= 1
```